# How to hide master page from Site Master Page and System Master Page dropdown in Site Master Page Settings

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, master-pages

I have created my custom master page. But i don't want to display it in Site Master Page and System Master Page dropdown in Site Master Page Settings.

How can i do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,Finally i got the answer.
To solve this issue you have to make changes in element.xml file.

```
<File Path="MasterPageGalleryModule\xyz.master" Url="xyz.Configuration.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
  <Property Name="Title" Value="xyz Masterpage" />
  <Property Name="UIVersion" Value="15" />      
  <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_masterpage_name;" />
  **<Property Name="PublishingHidden" Value="TRUE" />**
</File>
```

To hide master page you have to add new property i.e. PublishingHidden and set its value "TRUE".

Make sure that Publishing feature should be activated for particular sitecollection before deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this, But If i was to do this i would have written a script that will trigger on page load to read page url. If the url matches script will just find dropdowns and hide masterpage item.

Rather i would directly remove option from  tag.

Regards,
Keyur Pandya